# What software should I use to animate a simple 2d hexagon logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, svg, animation

I'm starting out in graphic design and am looking to animate this interlinked hexagon:

[image: Interlinked Hexagon]

Basically I want the blue/black vectors to extend 1 by 1 to create this logo. Is there any software/feature that can easily do this? Thank you.

Comment: Software recommendations are technically off-topic here, but there are lots, such as Adobe Animate, Blender, Synfig Studio, etc.  The software you tagged "Adobe Illustrator" is not animation software.

Comment: Depending on the medium you use, you may be able to achieve that effect using animated SVG or SVG+JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This can be very easily done in Adobe After Effects. But if you are not familiar with this software its interface may be a little bit scary at first sight.